# What Happens If The Sorcerers Run Out of Tokens?

Tags: small-world

In a game of Small World we were playing recently, we were facing Seafaring Sorcerers in a 5-player game, and they managed to expand *very* well, to the point where they were rapidly converting over most of the map. At one point, the player ran out of tokens to play.

**What Happens in This Case?**

Does their expansion halt completely? And if a sorcerer is killed, can they then re-use that token for conversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules address that specific case in the section on picking a race (page 3)

> If, on the other hand, a Special Power (or Race power) lets you take
>   additional Race tokens from the storage tray during the course of the
>   game, you are still limited by the total number of tokens physically
>   available. So a player with 18 Sorcerer tokens on the board won't be
>   able to use his Sorcerer power again until some of his tokens become
>   available.